# react-table v7 no data displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node-modules, react-table

Total noob here,
I was adapting the following tutorial (' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hson9BXU9F8&t=925s&ab_channel=Codevolution ') for my personal project, however my table does not show any data, I have tried comparing my project to the reference and even copying directly but i don't get any errors so its very difficult to pinpoint where I messed up.

TABLE COMPONENT

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import MOCK_DATA from './MOCK_DATA.json'
import { COLUMNS } from './columns'
import './table.css'

export const BasicTable = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  })

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}
```

COLUMNS COMPONENT

````
export const COLUMNS = [
    {
        //nombra la columna, se le puede poner cualquie nombre
        Header : 'id',
        //determina el elemento del JSON a acceder
        accesor: "id",
        disableFilters: true,
        sticky: 'left'
    },
    {
        Header : 'nombre_usuario',
        accesor: 'nombre_usuario'
    },
    {
        Header : 'correo_usuario',
        accesor: 'correo_usuario'
    },
    {
        Header : 'Rol_usuario',
        accesor: 'rol_usuario'
    },
    {
        Header : 'Estado_usuario',
        accesor: 'estado_usuario'
    },
    {
        Header : 'ident_usuario',
        accesor: 'id'
    },
]```

MOCK JSON EXAMPLE
````

[{"id":1,"nombre_usuario":"Skipton Noquet","pw_usuario":"r7ND2xcYb","correo_usuario":"snoquet0@naver.com","rol_usuario":"adipiscing","estado_usuario":"phasellus","ident_usuario":"937"}]

```
here is the repo from the tutorial i have been following, it works perfectly (it has an older version of react table, I tried it out and it didn't work either):
https://github.com/gopinav/React-Table-Tutorials.git
```

Comment: I somehow made it work but I don't understand how, I rewrote the columns folder but didn't change anything and it worked as intended

Answer (score 0):

Use page instead of rows

```
 {page.map(row => {...}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).